# Timing out of states in mapWithState

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, stateful

I wanted to write a function in mapwithstate which has timing-out enabled...

```
def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, 
                    key: String, value: Option[Int], 
                    state: State[Long]): Option[(String, Long)] = {
   if (state.isTimingOut()) {
     //write state to database
     return None
   } else if (state.exists) {
       var c = state.get()
       if (value.getOrElse(null) != null) {
         //update c
         c = c + value
         state.update(c)
       }
       Some(key,c)
     } else {
         Some(key,value.getOrElse(0).toLong)
       }
}
```

I wanted to know if a sate has been timing-out then it would probably doesn't exits, do my above code doesn't throw any exception..

In which case the value `Option[int]` doesn't exist .. if it is timed out?

Answer (score 1):

> In which case the value `Option[int]` doesn't exist .. if it is timed
>   out?

Yes, the `value` parameter of `mapWithState` would be `None` once the `State[S]` is timing out. When that happens, `state.isTimingOut()` will also be set to `true`.

[I've written](http://asyncified.io/2016/07/31/exploring-stateful-streaming-with-apache-spark/) regarding that matter exactly if you're interested in more characteristics of `mapWithState`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the explanation, so If I guess right,if state is not timing out , the value and state both exist?

Comment: @user2021147 If a value exists, the value will be a `Some[T]`. `State` will exist depending on *you*. If you fill it with a value, it will. If you remove the value, it won't.

Comment: so I gues I dont need this line in my code.//if (value.getOrElse(null) != null) since if the state is not timing out, the value always exist..

Comment: @user2021147 In your particular case, that's right, since you already check `state.isTimingOut` at the top of your `if-else`.